# define ssh config file in centos 6.9 after delete

Tags: ssh-config

I am working with centos 6.9 . I unconsciously deleted the ssh_config file which is located in /etc/ssh.

Any idea please to restore it , or to rewrite it? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: This sounds like a question about restoring files in general, not specifically about ssh-config or centos.

Comment: yes I agree , for my case it is ssh_config but it can be another file , any idea to resolve this please

Comment: Then this would be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80270/90810